# How do i patch in yocto?

Tags: patch, yocto, bitbake, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am attempting to build an image for the jetson-nano using yocto poky-warrior and meta-tegra warrior-l4t-r32.2 layer.

I've been following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481980/yocto-for-nvidia-jetson-fails-because-of-gcc-7-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object/56528785#56528785) because he had the same problem as me, and the answer on that thread fixed it, but then a new problem occoured.Building with

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

Stops with an error stating

```
ERROR: Task (…/jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
```

I've been told that applying the following patch would fix this problem:

```
diff --git a/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc b/meta/recipes-  core/busybox/busybox.inc
index 174ce5a8c0..e8d651a010 100644
--- a/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
+++ b/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
@@ -128,7 +128,7 @@ do_prepare_config () {
                ${S}/.config.oe-tmp > ${S}/.config
        fi
        sed -i 's/CONFIG_IFUPDOWN_UDHCPC_CMD_OPTIONS="-R -n"/CONFIG_IFUPDOWN_UDHCPC_CMD_OPTIONS="-R -b"/' ${S}/.config
-       sed -i 's|${DEBUG_PREFIX_MAP}||g' ${S}/.config
+       #sed -i 's|${DEBUG_PREFIX_MAP}||g' ${S}/.config
 }

 # returns all the elements from the src uri that are .cfg files
diff --git a/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb b/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb
index 3b9af6d739..350f7807a7 100644
--- a/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb
+++ b/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb
@@ -24,7 +24,7 @@ FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/libcrypt*.so.* ${libdir}/libcrypt-*.so ${libdir}/libowc
 S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

 BUILD_CPPFLAGS = "-I${STAGING_INCDIR_NATIVE} -std=gnu99"
-TARGET_CPPFLAGS = "-I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${includedir} -Wno-error=missing-attributes"
-CPPFLAGS_append_class-nativesdk = " -Wno-error=missing-attributes"
+TARGET_CPPFLAGS = "-I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${includedir} "
+CPPFLAGS_append_class-nativesdk = " "

 BBCLASSEXTEND = "nativesdk"
```

So I've made a libxcrypt.patch file and copy pasted the patch content and put the file in my poky meta layer. But how do I apply the patch?
I can't figure out what to do from here, do I need to make an bbappend file or add to one?- if so which one? or do I need to edit a .bb file?- maybe libxcrypt.bb? And do I need to add these lines:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://path/to/patch/file"
```

I've been trying to look at similar stackoverflow posts about this but they don't seem to be precise enough for me to work it out as I am completely new to yocto and the likes.

So far I've tried to add the lines

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://path/to/patch/file"
```

to the libxcrypt.bb file but it says it cannot find the file to patch.

Then I found out this could potentially be solved with adding ;striplevel=0 to the SRC_URI line, so I did this:

```
SRC_URI += "file://path/to/patch/file;striplevel=0"
```

Which did nothing. Then I tried to put

```
--- a/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
+++ b/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
```

In the top of the patch file, but this also did nothing.

This is the full error message without attempting to apply the patch:

```
ERROR: libxcrypt-4.4.2-r0 do_configure: configure failed
ERROR: libxcrypt-4.4.2-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/temp/log.do_configure.42560)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/temp/log.do_configure.42560
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| automake (GNU automake) 1.16.1
| Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
| License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
| This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
| There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
| 
| Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>
|        and Alexandre Duret-Lutz <adl@gnu.org>.
| AUTOV is 1.16
| NOTE: Executing ACLOCAL="aclocal --system-acdir=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.16" autoreconf -Wcross --verbose --install --force --exclude=autopoint -I /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/git/m4/ -I /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/
| autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
| autoreconf: running: aclocal --system-acdir=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.16 -I /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/git/m4/ -I /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force -I m4
| autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
| autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
| libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'm4'.
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltmain.sh'
| libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
| autoreconf: running: /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/autoconf --include=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/git/m4/ --include=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: running: /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/autoheader --include=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/git/m4/ --include=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
| configure.ac:31: installing 'm4/compile'
| configure.ac:30: installing 'm4/config.guess'
| configure.ac:30: installing 'm4/config.sub'
| configure.ac:17: installing 'm4/install-sh'
| configure.ac:17: installing 'm4/missing'
| Makefile.am: installing './INSTALL'
| Makefile.am: installing 'm4/depcomp'
| parallel-tests: installing 'm4/test-driver'
| autoreconf: running: gnu-configize
| autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
| NOTE: Running ../git/configure  --build=x86_64-linux        --host=aarch64-poky-linux           --target=aarch64-poky-linux         --prefix=/usr           --exec_prefix=/usr          --bindir=/usr/bin           --sbindir=/usr/sbin         --libexecdir=/usr/libexec           --datadir=/usr/share        --sysconfdir=/etc       --sharedstatedir=/com           --localstatedir=/var        --libdir=/usr/lib           --includedir=/usr/include       --oldincludedir=/usr/include        --infodir=/usr/share/info           --mandir=/usr/share/man         --disable-silent-rules          --disable-dependency-tracking           --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot  --disable-static
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/site/endian-little
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/site/arm-common
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/site/arm-64
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/site/common-linux
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/site/common-glibc
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/site/common
| configure: loading site script /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/site/endian-little
| checking for a BSD-compatible install... /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/hosttools/install -c
| checking whether build environment is sane... yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-strip... aarch64-poky-linux-strip
| checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/hosttools/mkdir -p
| checking for gawk... gawk
| checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
| checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
| checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
| checking host system type... aarch64-poky-linux-gnu
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-gcc... aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot
| checking whether the C compiler works... no
| configure: error: in `/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/build':
| configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
| See `config.log' for more details
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/temp/run.do_configure.42560:1 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/temp/log.do_configure.42560)
ERROR: Task (/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 883 tasks of which 848 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

This is the full error log when I try to add the lines to the libxcrypt.bb file to apply the patch:

```
ERROR: libxcrypt-4.4.2-r0 do_patch: Command Error: 'quilt --quiltrc /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/etc/quiltrc push' exited with 0  Output:
Applying patch libxcrypt.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 7
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|--- a/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
|+++ b/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
|diff --git a/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc b/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
|index 174ce5a8c0..e8d651a010 100644
|--- a/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
|+++ b/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox.inc
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
can't find file to patch at input line 20
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb b/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb
|index 3b9af6d739..350f7807a7 100644
|--- a/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb
|+++ b/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb
--------------------------
No file to patch.  Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
Patch libxcrypt.patch does not apply (enforce with -f)
ERROR: libxcrypt-4.4.2-r0 do_patch: 
ERROR: libxcrypt-4.4.2-r0 do_patch: Function failed: patch_do_patch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/build/tmp/work/aarch64-poky-linux/libxcrypt/4.4.2-r0/temp/log.do_patch.34179
ERROR: Task (/home/mci/yocto/dev-jetson-nano/layers/poky-warrior/meta/recipes-core/libxcrypt/libxcrypt.bb:do_patch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 811 tasks of which 793 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

I know this might be a trivial question for a lot, but as a new developer this is very hard to figure out on my own.

Comment: I did the patch manually and the build continued, but I would really like to learn how to patch, so an answer is still very much appreciated to how I could've used this patch properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of patching by adding patch files to meta layers and referencing them in SRC_URI only applies to patching the source code of packages. You can't use it to patch meta data (recipes) itself as you are trying to.

Instead you can manually change your local recipes, or add bbappends to your layer to change the existing recipes in poky. The best way to fix it permanently is to look for upstream fixes and update your poky layer if there are fixes, or if not send patches to upstream to fix it.

For the bbappend solution for libxcrypt, you would for example create a libxcrypt.bbappend with something like this as content:

```
TARGET_CPPFLAGS = "-I${STAGING_DIR_TARGET}${includedir} "
CPPFLAGS_reomve_class-nativesdk = "-Wno-error=missing-attributes"
```

Comment: I think I understand how to do this. I've created my own layer and added bbappend file for the libxcrypt changes. But is it possible to do with the busybox.inc file aswell? can I make a busybox.incappend file?

Comment: No you can only create appends for bb files. So you need to find the bb recipe, that includes the inc file, and bbappend to this file.

Comment: It builds with 0 errors, thank you!- Now I just hope it works on the jetson nano aswell.

Answer (score 4):

The patch you have is for the yocto/poky sources themselves (as opposed to the more usual case of having patches for the actual components that yocto builds and bbappends that modify recipes in other layers somehow).

So if you really want to use this patch, there's no need to "integrate" it into yocto, just run run `git am <patchfile>` in your poky root dir or use "patch" command directly. This is not very maintainable since your poky now differs from upstream but might work...

It should be possible to do the same changes using bbappends that you could then store in your own layer (this way the poky repo would be untouched) but the patch you have does not do that. This would be the most "proper" way of paching that you asked about in the comment -- but if you know that you aren't going to ever upgrade poky then it might not be work worth doing.

Comment: So doing it the "proper" way is to make my own layer and add it to ../build/conf/bblayer.bb. And in the layer have a .bbappend file with the "FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://path/to/patch/file"" lines and the .patch file?

Comment: No, you can't apply patch files to recipes automatically using Yocto itself. Yocto can't be used to patch Yocto ;). See my answer below for another version of what Jussi already said.

Comment: The bbappend in your layer would not add a patch file, but change the recipe source code directly or overwrite parts of it.